# Responsive Images - Differences with width: 100% / width:auto

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Currently working on a landing screen where users choose a colour theme on the site. There are two coloured sides that 'grow' on hover giving the effect of colouring the website seen on a mockup infront. (Check out the Codepen below to get what i mean, it's kinda hard to explain fully)

**Demo**: http://codepen.io/BAWKdesign/pen/PPvRjz/

To 'color' the mockup two images are used placed over one other.
It needs to be responsive so I've given the back image `width: 100%; height: auto;` which is also used to dictate the size of the parent div.
The top image is set to `width: auto; height: 100%;` as using width 100% causes the image to stretch and not clip.

The problem is, the overlaid image appears larger in size as you can see in the link below giving a cut up image effect. Perhaps there are differences in how the size is calculated when you swap 100% and Auto around?

Hopefully this is just me having a brain fart and I've made a rookie mistake somewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are by default `inline` elements meaning they naturally have some spacing around them. You are setting your other images to `position: absolute` which causes them to display similar to a `block` element - ie. no default spacing.

Simple solution is to add `display: block` to your image element:

```
.img {
    display: block;
}
```

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaNYpd)

Comment: Ah, I see!
Thankyou so much, have a great day dude!

Comment: I love that effect by-the-way. Looks great.

Comment: Cheers! Came up with the idea today, i'm glad you like it!